# air quality index calculation

Tags: r, excel, if-statement

If I have a statement in Excel like:

```
=IF(AND(Q1>=0,Q1<=12), 50/12*(Q1-0)+0, IF(AND(Q1>=12.1,Q1<=35.4),(100-51)/(35.4-12.1)*(Q1-12.1)+51, IF(AND(Q1>=35.5, Q1<=55.4), (150-101)/(55.4-35.5)*(Q1-35.5)+101, IF(AND(Q1>=55.5,Q1<=150.4), (200-151)/(150.4-55.5)*(Q1-55.5)+151,"NA" ))))
```

"Q1" is the cell in Column Q row 1. My question is, how can I translate the statement from Excel to R? I guess I should use multiple IF ELSE statements in R, but just not sure how I could organize them...

Thank you!

Comment: look at the function `ifelse` in R.

Comment: Could you provide some data and show what code you've already tried in `R`? That would make it a lot easier to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IF` in excel can be `ifelse` in R. The parameters are the same - look at the help file by typing `?ifelse`
`AND` in excel translates to `&` between the statements in R - see [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Logic.html)

```
#Assume your data is called Q
result = ifelse((Q>=0 & Q<=12), 50/12*(Q-0)+0, ifelse((Q>=12.1 & Q<=35.4),(100-51)/(35.4-12.1)*(Q-12.1)+51, ifelse((Q>=35.5 & Q<=55.4), (150-101)/(55.4-35.5)*(Q-35.5)+101, ifelse((Q>=55.5 & Q<=150.4), (200-151)/(150.4-55.5)*(Q-55.5)+151,"NA" ))))
```

Testing this, we have:

> Q = c(1,2,3,100,150,60)

```
> result
[1] "4.16666666666667" "8.33333333333333" "12.5"             "173.976817702845" "199.793466807165" "153.323498419389"
```

Hope that helps